# JETT HOW TO CONFIGURE DATA FROM A SPREADSHEET TO OTHER

Tags: jett

I Have two spreadsheet both with diferrent data. In one of the spreadsheet i want  a specific colum from the other.

This is the original code for the spreadsheet (acrruals)i want to add the colum:

${accruals.employee.name}

This is the other spreadsheet (PersonDetail) i want to extract the data for accruals spreadsheet:

${employee.fullName}

Im looking to add the colum ${baseWage.amountAsString} from PersonDetail to Accruals.

Is my first time using JETT i trying to edit the code :

${accruals.employee.name};productLicense;interactiveLicense;status;skill;certification;approver;purpose;apn;fte;uas;additionalInformation;personDate;isr;primaryLaborAccount;percentageAllocationRule;adjustmentRule;payRule;baseWage;badgeNumber;employmentTerm;groupAssignment;scheduleRuleSet;timeEntryMethod;organizationalGroup;jobPreferences;jobTransferSet">${employee.fullName};

But when i run the report the system show me the following error :

Error while processing report (Accruals (Spreadsheet Export)):
net.sf.jett.exception.TagParseException: One of the items in the "collections" attribute is not a
Collection in MultiForEach tag found at Accruals!B8: collections=${accruals.accrualsDataRows}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Stefano, could you attach your Excel template file? It's hard to figure out what you're trying to do from your explanation alone. Also, we don't have much info on the data structures of the accruals and employee beans, so it's difficult to find out if you'll be using them correctly in your template.

Comment: How can i attach it ? I try to do but i don't find how.

Comment: You can write me to my email sencarnacion@interboropr.com and i send you the templates.

Comment: What about creating a thread on https://sourceforge.net/p/jett/discussion/general/ and attaching the file there? Better sharing the file on a public location, so dropbox or google drive would work too.

Comment: I use the application "We Transfer" here is the link with the templates.  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/baec72980e769fcb4f5937279d0d4d6020180614155323/fc0ff9